# Springboot tomcat access from public IP address

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

Trying to figure out what's wrong with my Springboot Tomcat. I can't access my Web pages via my public IPv4 address.

Followed these steps to find a solution:

1. Turn off Windows firewall completely.
2. Used port forwarding via router: port 8080
3. Tried to access from browser `MyPublicIP:8080` -> resulted in `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.
4. Also tried messing with `application.properties`: `server.port` and tried to set other ports (8081,8888). Same steps above did not work.

I can access the server with my LAN's private IP, but not with my public one.

In addition, I checked in https://portchecker.co/ and ports were opened successfully.

What could it be?

Thanks!